# Java Generic type inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a base service declared like

```
BaseService<M, S>
```

I have another service that extends the base service declared like:

```
AnimalService extends BaseService<Animal, AnimalStatus>
```

Now, I need to have another Service to pass a model Dog instead of animal(Dog extends Animal), create a new service would work perfectly fine:

```
DogService extends BaseService<Dog, AnimalStatus>
```

The thing is, DogService is basically the same as AnimalService functional wise, so declaring another service just for dog is simply repeating the code of AnimalService.

Is there a way DogService can be declared so that it could reuse the code in Animal service while using the new model Dog or is there a way AnimalService  can be declared in a generic way so that it can accept the model dog as well?

Comment: `AnimalService<T extends Animal> extends BaseService<T, AnimalStatus>` would do the trick. This way, we can initialize it with `Animal` or any other subclass of `Animal` (e.g. `Dog`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to define `AnimalService` as a generic class itself like such:

```
AnimalService<T extends Animal> extends BaseService<T, AnimalStatus> {
    ...
}
```

This allows us to instantiate `AnimalService`s with types extending `Animal`, and even `Animal` itself:

```
class Animal {
    ... 
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    ...
}

...

final AnimalService<Animal> animalService = new AnimalService<Animal>();
final AnimalService<Dog> dogService = new AnimalService<Dog>();
```

In case we need a separate class `DogService`, to add or override some methods, we can also define it as:

```
class DogService extends AnimalService<Dog> {
    ...
}
```